# Adding like condition to db_select for section of string

Tags: nodes, database

What I am trying to do is find all of the basic pages where their titles contain 'Meetings' for example January Meetings

Here is what I have tried so far

```
$string = 'Meetings'; 
    $query = db_select('node', 'n');
    $query->fields('n');
    $query->condition('n.type', 'page', '=');
    $query->condition('n.changed', $time, '<=');
    $query->condition('n.status', 1, '=');
    $query->condition('n.title', '%'.db_like($string), 'LIKE');
    $result = $query->execute();
```

Which hasnt worked as it is trying to find pages that only contain 'Meetings' in their title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as it is trying to find pages that only contain 'Meetings' in their title.

Not quite - it's trying to find titles that *end with* the string "Meetings".

For a full wildcard match, the percent needs to be at both ends:

```
$query->condition('n.title', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE');
```